# insert background image in row with rowspan column

Tags: html, css

I have a table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

and CSS

```
table tr:nth-child(2n+1) { background:url("path"); }
```

But the result is here

[image]

i.e., the background image do not cover the row but the second row come up!
how to apply a background image to both row which is rowspaned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just give a class to the cells that you want to affect?

Here I'm giving the `rowspan` cells a class of `background`, and you can see that the background is applied to both rows:

```css
td.background {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/100");
}

td {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="background" rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

Hope this helps! :)